# Modified GDP measures

Tags: national-income

Just wondered if anyone was aware of any other modified GDP measures which take account of globalisation?

The point here is that when multinationals register profits in a country such as Ireland, it generates GDP growth.

However, this does not truly represent significant change in the Irish economy. Thus, Irish statistical bureaus have derived a'de-globalised' statistic known as GNI-star (GNI*).

https://www.centralbank.ie/docs/default-source/publications/economic-letters/vol-2021-no-1-is-ireland-really-the-most-prosperous-country-in-europe.pdf

I wondered if anyone was aware of similar statistics for other countries?

Would be appreciated.

Comment: A few decades ago, most countries published GNP which is similar to GNI. But it is easier and quicker to measure GDP so that became the preferred statistic.